# How to create dynamic query using criteriaquery for many-to-one

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, many-to-one

I have Person as one to many relationship with Address in JPA .

```
@Id 
    @Column(name="personid")
    private Long personId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;    

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="person",targetEntity=Address.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)      
    private List addressArray=new ArrayList<>();   
    public Person() {

    }
```

I want to create dynamic query using criteriaQuery so that I can fetch the person's firstname from the address object like "address.person.firstname".

Comment: Yep, no problem even with Lazy fetching.  Go do it.

Comment: @user2310289 ya but how using criteria api ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join() in Criteria to access a relationship.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Join